# Помогите опознать формат конфига

Tags: парсер, config, формат

Используется для описания метрик мониторинга в HP OpenView Operations Manager

Выглядит он так:

```
SYNTAX_VERSION 5

LOGFILE "online_log_clients_db"
        DESCRIPTION "log online_clients-db.log"
        LOGPATH "/usr/informix/LOGS/online_clients-db.log"
        INTERVAL "5m"
        CHSET ASCII
        FROM_LAST_POS
        SEVERITY Critical
        APPLICATION "DB"
        MSGGRP "Informix"
        OBJECT "OnlineLog"
        MSGCONDITIONS
                DESCRIPTION "out of virtual"
                CONDITION_ID "405966b8-fcd0-71e1-0c09-ac19be040000"
                CONDITION
                        TEXT "out of virtual"
                SET
                        SEVERITY Critical
                        MSGTYPE "sms"
                        TEXT "<$LOGFILE>: <$MSG_TEXT>"
                        NOTIFICATION
                DESCRIPTION "Server Stopped"
                CONDITION_ID "4059678a-fcd0-71e1-0c09-ac19be040000"
                CONDITION
                        TEXT "Server Stopped"
                SET
                        SEVERITY Critical
                        MSGTYPE "sms"
                        TEXT "<$LOGFILE>: <$MSG_TEXT>"
                        NOTIFICATION
                DESCRIPTION "Assert Failed"
                CONDITION_ID "b1c954ce-defd-71e2-1f00-ac19028f0000"
                CONDITION
                        TEXT "Assert Failed"
                SET
                        SEVERITY Critical
                        MSGTYPE "sms"
                        TEXT "<$LOGFILE>: <$MSG_TEXT>"
                        NOTIFICATION
                DESCRIPTION "Server Started"
                CONDITION_ID "f81ba2ea-b31b-71e3-1216-ac19cb0e0000"
                CONDITION
                        TEXT "Server Started"
                SET
                        SEVERITY Critical
                        MSGTYPE "sms"
                        TEXT "<$LOGFILE>: <$MSG_TEXT>"
                        NOTIFICATION
                DESCRIPTION "Bad Primary Chunk"
                CONDITION_ID "17b31fc6-1e68-71e5-0f4e-ac19028f0000"
                CONDITION
                        TEXT "Bad Primary Chunk"
                SET
                        SEVERITY Critical
                        MSGTYPE "sms"
                        TEXT "<$LOGFILE>: <$MSG_TEXT>"
                        NOTIFICATION
```

Может даже библиотеки(php, java, perl) какие есть для преобразования во что-то более адекватное, в XML например?

**UPD** Мне нужно именно описание самого формата, название, правила разбора, спецификация, ссылки на библиотеки его разбирающие.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=SYNTAX_VERSION+5+LOGFILE

Comment: @Visman спасибо конечно, но мне нужно узнать не где он используется (это я и так знаю), а то, как он называется, по каким правилам парсится и есть ли для этого готовые библиотеки

Comment: А какие нибудь ключевые слова по теме придумайте. я нашел несколько систем где это используется и вижу что в названии присутствует обычно SPI и даже с докой как то скудно, только отдельные примеры попадаются

Comment: @Mike добавил в начало вопроса. Тегов таких точно нет :) парсер то я уже написал, но подумалось, что вдруг это какой-то известный формат  и есть готовые, отлаженные, решения по его разбору

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опознать не получилось, готовых библиотек не нашел.

Если кому вдруг понадобится, то вот написал простой [парсер на PHP](https://github.com/rjhdby/HpomMetricsParser)